# using confusion matrix as scoring metric in cross validation in scikit learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am creating a pipeline in scikit learn,

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('bow', CountVectorizer()),  
    ('classifier', BernoulliNB()), 
])
```

and  computing the accuracy using cross validation

```
scores = cross_val_score(pipeline,  # steps to convert raw messages      into models
                     train_set,  # training data
                     label_train,  # training labels
                     cv=5,  # split data randomly into 10 parts: 9 for training, 1 for scoring
                     scoring='accuracy',  # which scoring metric?
                     n_jobs=-1,  # -1 = use all cores = faster
                     )
```

How can I report confusion matrix instead of 'accuracy'?

Answer (score 65):

You could use `cross_val_predict`([See the scikit-learn docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_predict.html)) instead of `cross_val_score`.

instead of doing :

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
scores = cross_val_score(clf, x, y, cv=10)
```

you can do :

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
y_pred = cross_val_predict(clf, x, y, cv=10)
conf_mat = confusion_matrix(y, y_pred)
```

Comment: It is specifically mentioned [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_predict.html) "It is not appropriate to pass these predictions into an evaluation metric. Use cross_validate to measure generalization error."

Comment: Mind that we are not using any evaluation metric here. As stated [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#cross-validation), the 'cross_val_predict' can be used for "Visualization of predictions obtained from different models.", which is what we are doing. However, it cannot be used in combination with 'cross_val_score' since the predictions are not the same.

Comment: `confusion_matrix` is an evaluation metric.

Comment: I am confused, what is the output of this function? It is the sum of each run?

Comment: I think (need to be checked, though) that every sample is only predicted once, because it appears only once in the test set.

Answer (score 34):

Short answer is "you cannot".

You need to understand difference between `cross_val_score` and cross validation as model selection method. `cross_val_score` as name suggests, works only on **scores**. Confusion matrix is not a score, it is a kind of summary of what happened during evaluation. A major distinction is that a score is supposed to return **an orderable object**, in particular in scikit-learn - a **float**. So, based on score you can tell whether method b is better from a by simply comparing if b has bigger score. You cannot do this with confusion matrix which, again as name suggests, is a matrix.

If you want to obtain confusion matrices for multiple evaluation runs (such as cross validation) you have to do this by hand, which is not that bad in scikit-learn - it is actually a few lines of code.

```
kf = cross_validation.KFold(len(y), n_folds=5)
for train_index, test_index in kf:

   X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
   y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]

   model.fit(X_train, y_train)
   print confusion_matrix(y_test, model.predict(X_test))
```

Comment: Doesnt this overwrite each confusion matrix if i use this in a jupyter notebook?

Comment: @FlixRo This does not overwrite each confusion matrix as each one is printed. This would be the case hwoever if print was not used: only the last matrix would be output in a notebook.

Comment: @CharlesG - this does overwrites confusion matrix in each run. You can store each confusion matrix in list and than calculate mean over it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59316264/2119941

Comment: To get this working I had to use `.iloc` - `X_train, X_test = X.iloc[train_index], X.iloc[test_index]`.

Comment: It's because you are using pandas instead of numpy (that OP used)

Comment: @lejlot thank you very much for answer. one question; which library you used for cross_validation.KFold? from sklearn import cross_validation gives an error.

Comment: It was in cross_validation in 2017 (https://scikit-learn.org/0.15/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.KFold.html), it moved to "model_selection" since then (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html#sklearn.model_selection.KFold)

Answer (score 13):

I think what you really want is **average of confusion matrices obtained from each cross-validation run**. @lejlot already nicely explained why, I'll just upgrade his answer with calculation of mean of confusion matrices:

Calculate confusion matrix in each run of cross validation. You can use something like this:

```
conf_matrix_list_of_arrays = []
kf = cross_validation.KFold(len(y), n_folds=5)
for train_index, test_index in kf:

   X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
   y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]

   model.fit(X_train, y_train)
   conf_matrix = confusion_matrix(y_test, model.predict(X_test))
   conf_matrix_list_of_arrays .append(conf_matrix)
```

On the end you can calculate your mean of list of numpy arrays (confusion matrices) with:

```
mean_of_conf_matrix_arrays = np.mean(conf_matrix_list_of_arrays, axis=0)
```

Comment: To get this working I had to use `.iloc` - `X_train, X_test = X.iloc[train_index], X.iloc[test_index]`.

Answer (score 7):

What you can do though is to define a scorer that uses certain values *from* the confusion matrix. See [here [link]](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#multimetric-scoring). Just citing the code:

```py
def confusion_matrix_scorer(clf, X, y):
    y_pred = clf.predict(X)
    cm = confusion_matrix(y, y_pred)
    return {'tn': cm[0, 0], 'fp': cm[0, 1],
            'fn': cm[1, 0], 'tp': cm[1, 1]}
cv_results = cross_validate(svm, X, y, cv=5,
                            scoring=confusion_matrix_scorer)
```

This will perform the cross validation for each of these four scorers and return the scoring dictionary `cv_results`, e.g., with keys `test_tp`, `test_tn`, etc. containing the confusion matrices' values from each cross-validation split.

From this you could reconstruct an average confusion matrix, but the `cross_val_predict` of [Xema](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45011622/3801913) seems more elegant for this.

Note that this will actually not work with `cross_val_score`; you'll need `cross_validate` (introduced in scikit-learn v0.19).

Side note: you could use *one* of these scorers (i.e. one element of the matrix) for  hyper-parameter optimization via grid search.

Comment: I think based on examples in [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html) confusion matrix returns different order than you have used in your functions: e.g. `TN` is at [0,0] and `TP` is at [1,1].

Comment: @Celdor is correct. See scikit-learn docs: "In binary classification, the count of true negatives is  C[0,0], false negatives is  C[1,0] , true positives is  C[1,1]  and false positives is C[0,1]". [source](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html#sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix)

Comment: thanks @Celdor and fpersyn. I actually have newer used it, so I couldn't spot these inconsistencies; I updated the code snippet to reflect the newest status in the docs following the first link. Apparently, there were two changes of this section in the docs since my initial copy-paste: [commit in 2018](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/commit/764abb6bc03aa6670c127da447de52edfaf4227b), [commit in 2020](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/commit/9acfaab9667c038686ef51881adce72721ede377)

Comment: Why is the `.predict()` being done across the entire input data `X`? Shouldn't it be done only in some test set `x_test`? And since, at each fold, a different test set is obtained from `cross_validate`, i don't understand how we can just pass `X` to both `confusion_matrix_scorer()` and `.predict()`.

Comment: @Murilo: the X passed to `cross_validate` will be split into train/test folds ([source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/ba51a075a1b1578e3d0a7b5eb69a3094b3edb2f3/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py#L282)) before being passed to the scorer/model.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to machine learning. If I understand correctly, the confusion matrix can obtain from 4 value, which are TP, FN, FP and TN. Those 4 value cannot obtain directly from scoring, but it is implied in accuracy, precision and recall.

Now it has 4 unknown TP, FN, FP and TN.

Eq1 : tp/(tp+fp)=P  [image]

Eq2 : tp/(tp+fn)=R  [image]

Eq3 : (tp+tn)/(tp+fn+fp+tn)=A  [image]

Assuming one of the unknown is 1, then it becomes 3 unknown and 3 equations. The relative value can be solved using system of equation.

1. P R A can obtain from scoring
2. cross_validate can get all 3 source at one time

```
def calculate_confusion_matrix_by_assume_tp_equal_to_1(r, p, a):
    # tp/(tp+fp)=P, tp/(tp+fn)=R, (tp+tn)/(tp+fn+fp+tn)=A
    fn = (1 / r) - 1
    fp = (1 / p) - 1
    tn = (1 - a - a * fn - a * fp) / (a - 1)
    return fn, fp, tn
```